# MapperParsingException: No handler for type [date_hour_minute_second] declared on field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I am developing a driver with Python Pyes client for Elasticsearch. I need mapping indexes with a date column has format No "date_hour_minute_second" based on docs http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/ also I check pyes docs https://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/reference/mapping/date-format.html

When I use "date_hour_minute_second" format for my field I got the exception mentioned in title.

Here is my field definition:

```
      "date": {
           "boost": 1.0,
           "store": "yes",
           "type": "date_hour_minute_second_fraction",
           "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
       }
```

I could not figure it out why it throws an exception like that even docs say it is supported.

Comment: Was I able to help? Please accept the answer if so! Otherwise post your problems and I'll try help further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you have put the mapping in slightly wrong, the `"date"` you have is the field name, you also need `"type": "date"` Try this:

```
"date": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "date_hour_minute_second_fraction",
    "store": "yes"
}
```

`"boost"` is 1.0 by default, so not needed.

Also I would question why you need `"store": "yes"`, unless you have turned global storing off (it's on by default, and the whole document you sent to elasticsearch can be retrieved).

Lastly, `"term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"` is not an applicable parameter for `"date"` types. Have a look [at the elasticsearch docs on core types and scroll to the date section](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @ramseykhalaf,

After a couple try I figured out that exactly what you said. Correct method was type: date and format: blbablba.

Thanks for reply and link.